# Is it unprofessional to add people back to the CCList when replying privately to the original sender?

Tags: professionalism, email

If someone sends an email to a group of people and a member of that group intentionally replies privately to the original sender (and not a mistake of forgetting to reply-all), then is it considered a private correspondence?  Is it acceptable for the original sender to re-add some or all members of the group to the reply of the private message?

Comment: In general, email CC is a nightmare. It's the number one source of business embarrassment.  It's a great question.  Personally I'd say "it's not acceptable to revert to group".

Comment: What do you mean by "acceptable"? Inconsiderate? Yes, probably (depending on the context). Bound to happen a few times? Yes, definitely. This is not something that you can control, so you might as well assume that all your private emails will be forwarded/CC'd to others (whether you want them to be or not).

Comment: This is especially true if your private reply contained information that could be considered useful to the others. If that information is useful, expect it to be shared.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Context is everything - so it will always depend on what they are responding too. In general it's proper decorum to consider it private correspondence.

Re-adding the rest of the group will depend on the content of the response. If you feel that it was intended as private then you should absolutely not re-add everyone.

If it was a response to something simple that the greater group would benefit from then ask if they mind you sharing the content.

In some cases people reply individually because they do not want to bother the list with hundreds of emails or simply to save you from a group embarrassment.

Comment: Also it may not have been private but rather cutting people out that may not have an interest in the discussion.  Adding someone back in because they are a stakeholder in this case would be appropriate.  For instance a PM sends out an email to everyone involved in the project.  A team member replies just to the PM asking questions to clarify.  The PM loops in a stakeholder, and a manager.  This is probably entirely appropriate.

Comment: Here are my two most commons reason for switching from collective to private : not bothering as your last point with bothering peoples and talking to colleagues without the clients contacts. The context of those are by definition good enough to know if you can reply with everyone back implicitely.

Comment: Yes, this is why context is everything.

Answer (score 3):

In general, when I get something privately(or send something privately) in the middle of a long group chain of emails, it is because the person on the other end wants to bring up a point without getting others, perhaps very senior others or clients) involved. If my response to that email needs to be sent to the group, then usually I discuss it with the person who sent me the private email and then add information to the original chain of emails rather than re-adding people to a private email.  This keeps what was supposed to be private, private and puts the information that needs to go public, public.

This prevents embarrassment and allows people to feel as if their private communications are not going public which tends to result in people being more willing to give you private information that perhaps they would not want senior managers to see.  So for instance:

There is a long email chain on a data import problem that includes the client. An Account Manager privately emails me to tell me that the client is upset that something has not been resolved and can I prioritize this. I call her on the phone and tell her the problem is at the client end and together we decide how to respond to the original email. Then one of us sends the response we agreed on to the entire group as a response to the original email chain. This also has the advantage of keeping all info that should be in the entire chain in it and and adds it to the latest response (because we may have gotten more in the meantime) so that all information is in one chain.

Be especially careful about re-adding people if the private message was blunt or disparaging of someone in the chain or their management. Suppose the private email said something like, "I know Joe is being a jerk here, but he does need to get an answer to the CEO today. I'm swamped, can you do me a big favor and get him off my back?" clearly adding other people back into an email like that is going to upset Joe, upset other managers and possibly make sure the person who wrote it doesn't ever help you out in the future. It will also be a clue to everyone in the chain that you are not to be trusted.

If the email seemed to be an obvious error (i.e., there is no reason why it should not have gone to the whole chain), then I usually email the person back to ask them to include everyone. That saves face for them which is almost always a good thing to do.

Comment: +1 For the second to last paragraph about being careful of sharing an unprofessional email, that's especially true when you re-add people after a long private aside. Something unprofessional may have been said 10 emails ago, but you forgot about and and just accidentally sent it to your customer.

Comment: @DavidK, that's one reason why I always go back to the original thread if I need to re-add people.

Answer (score 2):

If someone sent you a private message then that person made a concious decision to contact you – and *only* you – privately.

They may have done so simply because they thought the rest of the group wasn't interested in this specific message, or they may have done so because they didn't want to send that message to the rest of the group for any number of reasons.

Telling the difference between the two is not always easy, and the safe path is always to *ask*: "is it okay if I forward out correspondence to the rest of the group?"

Comment: I think this is the best answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can send *your* message to whomever you want.  Where you'll get into trouble is forwarding somebody *else's* private message without consent.  Most email programs these days include the replied-to message by default, so reply + CCing others causes them to see the private message.  Watch out for that.

One way around this is to ask for permission to share, as others have suggested.  Another way -- IMO better when the thread is already long -- is to address the point without forwarding.  Something like:

> I was asked how we'll guarantee data integrity when doing large asynchronous writes.  We plan to do this by...

Or:

> Several people have asked me whether the new match for our retirement plan is retroactive to the beginning of the year. [answer]

If somebody made an astute point and you want to give credit, get permission and then say something like:

> Alice pointed out that the export operation could run for a long time and holding the global lock until the end could prevent backups from running.  We'll address this by...

Answer (score 1):

I make too often the mistake of answering privately while intending to answer to the whole group. In such occasions usually the person answered just answers back to me pointing that I seem to have clicked the wrong button. Then I tank him and resend the original message to the group. I think this is the obvious and most safe and respectful course of actions.

However, if it were clearly obvious that the message was intended to the group and waiting to the sender to fix the mistake could harm communication with an undesirable delay - for example, if there was a deadline on the debated issue - it would be fine to CC everybody again in the answer.

Comment: Agreed.  If it's obvious that the message was actually intended for the larger audience then adding people back to the copy would be acceptable.  To be safe it would be best to confirm with the private sender first.